# YouTube API v3 Standardfeeds

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

can you query the YouTube Standardfeeds with the API v3 and will they be deprecated in the future?

Answer (score 1):

We don't have standard feeds in the YouTube API V3.0 yet but are working on a new mechanism for V3.0.